# Linked files with TFS 2015 Branching

Tags: c#, tfs

We have started experimenting with branching in TFS to keep seperate branches for Dev, Production, and QA, but I am running into the following problem:

We have 2 different solutions which share some common classes and we handled this by using the "Add as link" functionality of VS, after branching when I check a class out in the Development branch of our 1st solution, it checks out that same (linked) file in the Production branch of our 2nd solution.

I have found a work-around for this by removing the file from the 1st solution and then adding it as a linked file again, but this time using the file from the Dev (or appropriate) branch of the 2nd solution. But this is a lot of manual work as we have some 100+ classes and 3 branches.

Can anyone suggest a better solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't share code by linking code files between projects. Encapsulate the shared functionality in a common project and share the project between dependent projects either via direct project references or via a package manager such as NuGet. The latter gives more flexibility around versioning, but requires a bit more effort.

Also, I can't say for sure without more context, but isolating code by branch typically is a bad practice. The ideal is that you have a single build of your software that can be deployed to every environment in a deployment pipeline via a release/deployment process. Isolating code in branches encourages you to build once for each environment, which destroys all of your prior testing -- the code you build and deploy out of your "production" branch isn't necessarily the same stuff you just tested from your "QA" branch.

Comment: While this is not the easiest solution, or a quick fix that I was hoping for this is the right way to do it. At the time this was not possible, but we have made changes in our system to allow us to add all these functionalities into a common project. Thank you for the suggestion.